# Do all four-letter-words have four letters?

Tags: idioms, slang

Two vulgar words I know have five letters but I've been told they are considered four-letter-words in spite of it. The explanation I got was that in such cases vulgarity matters more than the number of letters. Is that so ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A red carpet, literally, is a carpet that is red. A red carpet, figuratively, can be a carpet that is actually blue, or no carpet at all, just some pavement painted red.

A four-letter word, literally, is a word with exactly four letters. A four-letter word, figuratively, is a swear word.

*Literally*, literally, means "literally". *Literally*, figuratively, means "virtually".

You get the idea.

So the question remains whether the figurative use of *four-letter word* to mean "swear word with any number of letters" has any traction. In my neck of the woods, it does not, and neither does it [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-letter_word). But that does not mean it just never can be used figuratively anywhere ever. Any word at all can. The speaker/writer merely needs to understand, and admit, that his usage is figurative.

Comment: Your answer loses the plot when you get into the literally/figuratively distinction. 

The short answer is 'yes, all four letter words contain four letters'. 'Bitch' and 'Asshole' are not four letter words.

Comment: I agree your statement concisely captures Reg's answer, and according to him "bitch" is not a 4LW. That said, round here, we do apply the term 4LW to "bitch" and all other vulgar expletives, as well as (humorously) in phrases like "At this company, *management* is a four-letter word" (using 4LW as a stand-in for *vulgarity*, the pun being *management*, in a literal sense, has 10 letters).